# What is the point of using asterisk wildcard with recursive operation?

Tags: regular-expression, wildcards

i'm reading LPIC-1 PDF's. It says:

> In general to copy all the contents of a directory we use:
>
> cp -r SOURCE_PATH/* DEST_PATH

But i can't understand why -r option itself without * is not enough? It should be right?

Thanks.

Edit: i tried and results are interesting.
First, if destination not exist, * wildcard in source gives error as there is no destination directory. Without * cp copies all hidden files including hidden in top and subdirectories.

On the other hand, if destination exist and we use * wildcard in source, cp copies all files in the top except hidden ones, but subdirectory hidden files included.

```
[rocky@rocky ~]$ tree -a test1
test1
├── .hiddentestfile1
├── test2
│   ├── .hiddentestfile2
│   └── testfile2
└── testfile1

1 directory, 4 files
[rocky@rocky ~]$ cp -r test1/* newdest
cp: target 'newdest' is not a directory
[rocky@rocky ~]$ cp -r test1/ newdest
[rocky@rocky ~]$ tree -a newdest
newdest
├── .hiddentestfile1
├── test2
│   ├── .hiddentestfile2
│   └── testfile2
└── testfile1

1 directory, 4 files
[rocky@rocky ~]$ rm -r newdest
[rocky@rocky ~]$ mkdir newdest
[rocky@rocky ~]$ cp -r test1/* newdest
[rocky@rocky ~]$ tree -a newdest
newdest
├── test2
│   ├── .hiddentestfile2
│   └── testfile2
└── testfile1

1 directory, 3 files
```

Comment: If the source directory contains subdirectories then `-r` is necessary to recursive through the tree.

Comment: Have you set up a small example to test this for yourself?

Comment: @doneal24 The question is regarding `*`, not `-r`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ok, I read the options backwards. Then adding the `*` to the source directory will generally exclude copying dot files.

Comment: Thank you @doneal24 but Kusalananda is right. I know -r option. * has also same function. So is there any logical  reason to use both together.

Comment: If the directory `SOURCE_PATH/.git` exists, it will not be copied if you add the `*` to your copy command. Also, `-r` and `*` do not have the same function. `-r` is an option to `cp` to be recursive over all of the files/directories on the command line. `*` is expanded by the shell to match all files/directories that don't begin with a dot. This expansion is passed on to `cp`. Try creating the directory `SOURCE_PATH/foo` and run the `cp` with `*` but not `-r`.

Comment: These are good additions to your question. What do you get with `rm -r newdest; mkdir newdest ; cp test1/* newdest`?

Comment: Hİ, @doneal24 of course, subdirectory test2 omitted as expected and non-hidden files in top copied.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cp -r SOURCE_PATH/* DEST_PATH
> ```

Copies each of the (non-hidden) files or directories and their contents recursively into DEST_PATH (assuming that's a directory or symlink to directory).

Then if SOURCE_PATH contains for instance `file`, `dir` and `.git`, you end up with `DEST_PATH/file` and `DEST_PATH/dir`.

Beware that if `DEST_PATH` didn't exist or was not a directory and `SOURCE_PATH` contained only one non hidden file or directory (say `SOURCE_PATH/file`), then that would become `cp -r SOURCE_PATH/file DEST_PATH` (a copy-to instead of copy-into) which means DEST_PATH would be created (or overwritten) as a copy of `file`. Appending a `/` to DEST_PATH in the command ensures that doesn't happen (guarantees either a copy-into or failure with *not a directory*; see also the `-t` option of GNU `cp`).

With:

> ```
> cp -r SOURCE_PATH DEST_PATH
> ```

You're copying the SOURCE_PATH directory (and all its contents recursively, including hidden files) into DEST_PATH (assuming again it exists and is a directory), so you end up with `DEST_PATH/SOURCE_PATH`, `DEST_PATH/SOURCE_PATH/{.git,dir,file}`. So it gives a different outcome altogether.

Here to copy all the *contents* of SOURCE_PATH (including hidden files) and not SOURCE_PATH itself into DEST_PATH, you'd rather use:

```
cp -r SOURCE_PATH/. DEST_PATH
```

Besides also including hidden files (which assuming zsh, you could also do with `cp -r SOURCE_PATH/*(D) DEST_PATH/`) that also has the advantage of not failing with a *too many arguments* error if SOURCE_PATH has too many non-hidden files, and not to report an error if SOURCE_PATH is empty. Also, if DEST_PATH doesn't exists it ends up being created as a copy of SOURCE_PATH.

With the GNU implementation of `cp`, you can do the same with:

```
cp -rT SOURCE_PATH DEST_PATH
```

(`-T` aka `--no-target-directory` forces a copy-to instead of a copy-into even when the destination is a directory).